# How to remove nth column from the text table in powershell?

Tags: powershell, format

Let’s say I am working with a nicely formatted table. Take `kubectl` output for example:

```
NAME            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP          NODE   NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
me-pod-name     2/2     Running   0          6s      10.0.0.10   node1  <none>           <none>
me-pod-name-2   1/1     Running   0          6d18h   10.0.1.20   node2  <none>           <none>
me-pod-name-3   1/1     Running   0          11d     10.0.0.30   node3  <none>           <none>
```

I tend to watch such output and log changes a lot. In this case, I would like to remove one of the middle columns from the table and still get a nice output.

To demonstrate, suppose I want to remove the `AGE` column, as it changes a lot and is useless for watching when the resource is young:

```
NAME            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   IP          NODE   NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
me-pod-name     2/2     Running   0          10.0.0.10   node1  <none>           <none>
me-pod-name-2   1/1     Running   0          10.0.1.20   node2  <none>           <none>
me-pod-name-3   1/1     Running   0          10.0.0.30   node3  <none>           <none>
```

My question is: **How do I easily remove such column and still output nicely formatted table, with all other columns intact?**

The columns are not always the same size (e.g. `AGE` is not always 8 characters wide).

- **I’d like to find some reusable, one-liner solution.** I work with a lot of CLI tools (not just k8s-related) and often need to filter output when passing data between them.
- **Also, I’d like to avoid pattern-based solution,** where I need to produce regex for each column I want to remove. (I am *able* to do it, but that requires me writing specific solution for each use case.)

I tried to work with `ConvertFrom-String` and `Format-Table`, but this messes a lot with a data format (e.g. `"1/1"` is being treated as a date format, which is not true for the case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking at is Fixed-Width data.
To handle that, the `Import-Csv` won't do so I made a couple of functions some time ago to convert from and to Fixed-Width data.

```
function ConvertFrom-FixedWidth {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([PSObject[]])]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string[]]$Data,

        [int[]]$ColumnWidths = $null,    # an array of integers containing the width in characters for each field
        [string[]]$Header = $null,       # if given, a string array containing the columnheaders
        [switch]$AllowRaggedContent      # if set, the function accepts the last items to be trimmed.
    )

    # If the data is sent through the pipeline, use $input to collect is as array
    if ($PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.ExpectingInput) { $Data = @($Input) }
    # or use : $Data = $Input | ForEach-Object { $_ }

    if (!$ColumnWidths) {
        Write-Verbose "Calculating column widths using first row"
        # Try and determine the width of each field from the top (header) line.
        # This can only work correctly if the fields in that line do not contain space
        # characters OR if each field is separated from the next by more than 1 space.

        # temporarily replace single spaces in the header row with underscore
        $row1 = $Data[0] -replace '(\S+) (\S+)', '$1_$2'  

        # Get the starting index of each field and add the total length for the last field
        $indices = @(([regex] '\S+').Matches($row1) | ForEach-Object {$_.Index}) + $row1.Length
        # Calculate individual field widths from their index
        $ColumnWidths = (0..($indices.Count -2)) | ForEach-Object { $indices[$_ + 1] - $indices[$_] }
    }

    # Combine the field widths integer array into a regex string like '^(.{10})(.{50})(.{12})'
    $values = $ColumnWidths | ForEach-Object { "(.{$_})" }
    if ($AllowRaggedContent) {
        # account for fields that are too short (possibly by trimming trailing spaces)
        # set the last item to be '(.*)$' to capture any characters left in the string.
        $values[-1] = '(.*)$'
    }
    $regex = '^{0}' -f ($values -join '')

    Write-Verbose "Splitting fields and generating output"
    # Execute a scriptblock to convert each line in the array.
    $csv = & { 
        switch -Regex ($Data) {
            $regex {
                # Join what the capture groups matched with a comma and wrap the fields
                # between double-quotes. Double-quotes inside a fields value must be doubled.
                ($matches[1..($matches.Count - 1)] | ForEach-Object { '"{0}"' -f ($_.Trim() -replace '"', '""') }) -join ','
            }
        }
    }
    if ($Header) { $csv | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header $Header }
    else { $csv | ConvertFrom-Csv }
}

function ConvertTo-FixedWidth {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([String[]])]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [PSObject[]]$Data,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [ValidateRange(1, 8)]
        [int]$Gap = 2
    )

    # if the data is sent through the pipeline, use $input to collect is as array
    if ($PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.ExpectingInput) { $Data = @($Input) }
    # or use : $Data = $Input | ForEach-Object { $_ }

    # get the headers from the first object in the correct order
    Write-Verbose "Retrieving column headers"
    $headers = $Data[0].PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {$_.Name }

    # calculate the maximum width for each column
    Write-Verbose "Calculating column widths"
    $columnWidths  = @{}
    foreach ($item in $Data) {
        foreach ($column in $headers) {
            $length = [Math]::Max($item.$column.Length, $column.Length)
            if ($column -ne $headers[-1]) { $length += $Gap }
            if ($columnWidths[$column]) { $length = [Math]::Max($columnWidths[$column], $length) }
            $columnWidths[$column] = $length
        }
    }

    # output the headers, all left-aligned
    $line = foreach ($column in $headers) {
        "{0, -$($columnWidths[$column])}" -f $column
    }
    # output the first (header) line
    $line -join ''

    # regex to test for numeric values
    $reNumeric = '^[+-]?\s*(?:\d{1,3}(?:(,?)\d{3})?(?:\1\d{3})*(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)$'

    # next go through all data lines and output formatted rows
    foreach ($item in $Data) {
        $line = foreach ($column in $headers) {
            $padding = $columnWidths[$column]
            # if the value is numeric, align right, otherwise align left
            if ($item.$column -match $reNumeric) { 
                $padding -= $Gap
                "{0, $padding}{1}" -f $item.$column, (' ' * $Gap)
            }
            else {
                "{0, -$padding}" -f $item.$column
            }
        }
        # output the line
        $line -join ''
    }
}
```

Having these functions in place, using your example, you could do this:

```
# get the fixed-width data from file and convert it to an array of PSObjects 
$data = (Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test.txt') | ConvertFrom-FixedWidth -AllowRaggedContent -Verbose

# now you can remove any column like this
$data = $data | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty 'AGE'

# show on screen
$data | Format-Table -AutoSize

# save to disk as new fixed-width file
$data | ConvertTo-FixedWidth -Gap 3 -Verbose | Set-Content -Path 'D:\Output.txt'

# or you can save it as regular CSV to disk
$data | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Result on screen:

> ```
> NAME          READY STATUS  RESTARTS IP        NODE  NOMINATED NODE READINESS GATES
> ----          ----- ------  -------- --        ----  -------------- ---------------
> me-pod-name   2/2   Running 0        10.0.0.10 node1 <none>         <none>         
> me-pod-name-2 1/1   Running 0        10.0.1.20 node2 <none>         <none>         
> me-pod-name-3 1/1   Running 0        10.0.0.30 node3 <none>         <none>
> ```

Result as saved to Fixed-Width file:

> ```
> NAME            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   IP          NODE    NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
> me-pod-name     2/2     Running          0   10.0.0.10   node1   <none>           <none>         
> me-pod-name-2   1/1     Running          0   10.0.1.20   node2   <none>           <none>         
> me-pod-name-3   1/1     Running          0   10.0.0.30   node3   <none>           <none>
> ```

Comment: Thanks for those. While I might tinker it to match some cases better it is definitely the most fitting solution for catch-all scenarios. I hope this will help others find them easily. The full command pipe I've used with it is the following (personally I don't like it going through files, but I get it for the simplicity):
`kubectl get pod | ConvertFrom-FixedWidth |Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty 'AGE' |  ConvertTo-FixedWidth `

Answer (score 1):

As an aside: For a given utility, you may be able to
tackle the problem at the *source*, by [using its options to emit a *machine-parseable* data format](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/#custom-columns) rather than pretty-printed text (e.g, JSON), which PowerShell may be able to parse into *objects* (e.g., `ConvertFrom-Json`), which you can then easily select properties from and format for display with PowerShell's `Format-*` cmdlets.

---

**Parsing and transforming fixed-width columnar text output in PowerShell:**

Generally, it's best to parse the input text into custom objects (`[pscustomobject]` instances), which makes them suitable for *further programmatic processing* and also *reformatting* using PowerShell's flexible `Format-*` cmdlets.

To what extent this parsing can be automated without advance knowledge depends on the specifics of a given utility's fixed-width output (the assumption is that trailing whitespace in each column should be trimmed):

- **Automated parsing**:

  - If the following condition is met, you can automatically determine the extent of the columns and values:

    - The columns are separated by separator strings (at least one character).
    - *and* the column names and row values themselves have no *embedded* instances of this separator string (except for trailing spaces).
  - **Custom function `Select-Column`**, whose source code is printed below, can perform this **automated parsing via a regex that describes the separator string**.
- Otherwise, you have to **parse by known-in-advance column widths / starting positions**:

  - That is, you have to know the width of all individual columns / their starting positions and parse based on that. [Theo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59543676/45375) shows how to do that.

---

In the case of `kubectl`, the columns are separated by *2* spaces, whereas the column names contain only 1 space, and the values none (in your sample output), so the prerequisite for automated parsing is met.

Custom function `Select-Column`, whose source code is below, can parse the text into custom objects (`[pscustomobject]` instances) via regex   `+` as the column separator expression (2 or more spaces), and the resulting objects are suitable for further programmatic processing and formatting in PowerShell.

You can simply pipe `kubectl` output to it.
With up to 4 selected columns, the resulting objects are implicitly formatted as a table (implied `Format-Table`); with 5 or more, as a list (implicit `Format-List`).
You can pipe to `Format-*` cmdlets explicitly to control the formatting.

```sh
# Parse all columns except 'Age' into custom objects and format them as a table:
kubectl ... | Select-Column '  +' -Exclude Age | Format-Table
```

The above yields:

```
NAME          READY STATUS  RESTARTS IP        NODE  NOMINATED NODE READINESS GATES
----          ----- ------  -------- --        ----  -------------- ---------------
me-pod-name   2/2   Running 0        10.0.0.10 node1 <none>         <none>
me-pod-name-2 1/1   Running 0        10.0.1.20 node2 <none>         <none>
me-pod-name-3 1/1   Running 0        10.0.0.30 node3 <none>         <none>
```

You could wrap such calls in a custom function, including piping to `Format-Table`, but note that doing the latter means that the output is again not suitable for programmatic processing, because `Format-*` calls output *formatting instructions*, not data.

If you wanted the output to be table-formatted *by default* even for 5 or more properties, more work would be needed: you'd have to assign a distinct (virtual) type name to the output objects and define [formatting data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml) for that type.

---

#### `Select-Column` source code:

```sh
function Select-Column {
  <#
  .SYNOPSIS
  Parses columnar text data into custom objects.

  .DESCRIPTION
  Parses line-based columnar text data into custom objects, based on a 
  column-separator pattern specified as a regular expression.

  By default, the values from all columns are returned as properties of the output
  objects.
  Use -Name to extract only given columns, or -ExcludeName to exclude columns.

  .PARAMETER SeparatorPattern
  A regular expression specifying what text separates the column names / values
  in the input text.

  The default is ' +', i.e. any run of one or more spaces, which works with
  fixed-width columns whose column names and values have no embedded spaces.

  .PARAMETER Name
  The names of one more columns to extract from the input text.
  These names must match existing columns.
  By default, all columns are returned.

  .PARAMETER Exclude
  The names of one more input columns to exclude from the properties of the output
  objects.
  These names must match existing columns.

  .PARAMETER InputObject
  This parameter receives the individual lines of input text via the pipeline.
  the pipeline.

  Alternatively, you can pass the input text as a single multi-line string, both
  via the pipeline and directly to this parameter.

  .EXAMPLE
  'col1 col2', 'val1 val2' | Select-Column

  Converts the line-by-line input into custom objects with properties 'col1'
  and 'col2' whose values are 'val1' and 'val2', based on runs of 1 or more
  spaces acting as separators.

  .EXAMPLE
  'col 1  col 2', 'val1  val2' | Select-Column ' {2,}' -Exclude 'col 2'

  Converts the line-by-line input into custom objects based on two or more spaces
  as separators, excluding values from column 'col 2'.
  #>

  [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'All')]
  param(
    [Parameter(Position = 0)]
    [Alias('s')]
    [string[]] $SeparatorPattern = ' +'
    ,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Include', Position = 1)]
    [Alias('n')]
    [string[]] $Name
    ,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Exclude')]
    [Alias('x')]
    [string[]] $ExcludeName
    ,
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
    [string] $InputObject
  )

  begin {
    Set-StrictMode -Version 1
    $lineIndex = 0
  }

  process {
    foreach ($line in $InputObject -split '\r?\n' -ne '') {

      # Split the line into colum names / fields.
      $fields = $line -split $SeparatorPattern
      # Process the header row
      if ($lineIndex++ -eq 0) {
        $ndx = 0
        # Map column names to their indices.
        $nameToIndex = @{ }
        foreach ($n in $fields) {
          $nameToIndex[$n] = $ndx++
        }
        # Based on the given column names, build a list of indices
        # to extract, and create an ordered hashtable with the specified
        # column names to serve as a template for the output objects.
        $unknownName = $null
        if ($Name) {
          # only the specified columns
          $unknownName = (Compare-Object -PassThru $fields $Name).Where({ $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' })
        }
        elseif ($ExcludeName) {
          # all but the specified columns
          $Name, $unknownName = (Compare-Object -PassThru $fields $ExcludeName).Where({ $_.SideIndicator -eq '<=' }, 'Split')
        }
        else {
          $Name = $fields # default to all columns
        }
        if ($unknownName) { Throw "Unknown column name(s): $unknownName" }
        if (-not $Name) { Throw "You have selected no output columns." }
        $oht = [ordered] @{ }
        $outColIndices = foreach ($n in $Name) {
          $oht[$n] = $null 
          $nameToIndex[$n] # output the index
        }
      }
      # Process a data row.
      else {
        # Fill in the ordered hashtable with this line's field values...
        $ndx = 0
        foreach ($n in $Name) {
          $oht[$n] = $fields[$outColIndices[$ndx++]]
        }
        # ... and construct and output a custom object from it.
        [pscustomobject] $oht
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you missed my intention here. Kubectl is just an example. I work with many such tools. In the past, I did manually format the raw output, written my won wrappers for command and messed with problem individually. However, it's not a good solution going forward, as I can't write my own wrappers for each CLI tool I use for cluster/cloud management. There's too many of them. And not each will give me the possibility to mess with the output format or to easily recreate the output from raw formats like JSON. I was looking for repeatable solution.

Comment: The `Select-Column` function does, however, do what I was going for, and **it can be used instead of the answer above** from Theo. Alas, there's no possibility to choose them both as valid responses.

Comment: @user12363468: Understood re intent; I've revised the answer substantially, with a link to Theo's answer for contrast. Re accepting answers: While you can only _accept_ one, with 15 or more reputation points you can also _up-vote_ additional helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

A rather late answer...
I have a similar solution as [@Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) in the form of a PowerShell cmdlet called [`ConvertFrom-SourceTable`](https://github.com/iRon7/ConvertFrom-SourceTable) which I am trying to maintain. It *automatically* recognizes a lot of known table formats and converts them to objects accordingly, for details see the related [project site](https://github.com/iRon7/ConvertFrom-SourceTable).
I agree with [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) that you should try to tackle the problem at the source but that is not always possible. Besides, if there was a standard for fixed width text tables, it would place the statement in a complete different perspective knowing that the closest to a fixed width text table is probably a [CSV file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), which format is not fully standardized, only supports strings (in PowerShell) and above all, hard to read for a human. From my perspective: *if a human can read it, a program should be able to interpret it*. Programs should help humans were possible, not vise versa.
In contradiction to Theo's solution, my cmdlet doesn't define the column boundaries by 2 or more spaces (as there is no guaranty that columns are just separated by single space) but on a combination of the header, the ruler and the data that follows. Anyways, this was actually the cause of an issue I was dealing with for the given table in question: The `NOMINATED NODE` column was split into two separated columns causing a duplicated `NODE`column.
Considering the fact that splitting columns based on 2 or more spaces is not natural, it is obvious in this table that the `NOMINATED NODE` and `READINESS GATES` are single columns as there is no data under the `NODE` - and `GATES` header texts.
This constrain has kept me busy for a while but is now incorporated in the last update of the [`ConvertFrom-SourceTable`](https://github.com/iRon7/ConvertFrom-SourceTable):

```
Install-Script -Name ConvertFrom-SourceTable # https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable
. .\ConvertFrom-SourceTable.ps1              # Load (dot-source) the script

$Data = Get-Content .\Table.txt -Raw | ConvertFrom-SourceTable
```

<sub>**Note:** You might also consider to omit the `-Raw` switch and *stream* each individual line. This will use less memory but the `ConvertFrom-SourceTable` cmdlet is only able to base its decisions (such as column recognition) on the first data row rather than the whole table.</sub>

```
# now you can remove any column like as per Theo's answer
$Data = $Data | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty 'AGE'

# and create a table without horizontal ruler
$Header = [Ordered]@{}
$Data[0].PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {$Header[$_.Name] = $_.Name}
[PSCustomObject]$Header, $Data | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Set-Content .\NewTable.txt
```

**Result**

> ```
> NAME          READY STATUS  RESTARTS IP        NODE  NOMINATED NODE READINESS GATES
> me-pod-name   2/2   Running 0        10.0.0.10 node1 <none>         <none>
> me-pod-name-2 1/1   Running 0        10.0.1.20 node2 <none>         <none>
> me-pod-name-3 1/1   Running 0        10.0.0.30 node3 <none>         <none>
> ```

<sub>Note that the `ConvertFrom-SourceTable` cmdlet is still able to read back the above resulting table despite the fact that the columns are separated by a single space</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method. First put all the data in a plain text file("C:\Temp.txt") Then this script will first take all data into a csv file, Then format it.

```
Get-Content "C:\Temp.txt" | Export-CSV "C:\Temp.csv"
Import-CSV "C:\Temp.csv" | Select-Object NAME, READY, STATUS, RESTARTS, IP, NODE, NOMINATED NODE, READINESS GATES
Remove-Item "C:\Temp.txt"
Remove-Item "C:\Temp.csv"
```

Or if any command generated the output no need of putting it into a text file.

```
TheCommand | Export-CSV "C:\Temp.csv"
Import-CSV "C:\Temp.csv" | Select-Object NAME, READY, STATUS, RESTARTS, IP, NODE, NOMINATED NODE, READINESS GATES
Remove-Item "C:\Temp.txt"
Remove-Item "C:\Temp.csv"
```

Comment: While it is a method, I'd like to avoid it going through files. What is more important I  wouldn't like to craft the desired property list for every column that's ok to be shown. Some tables are far too dynamic for that.