# Sort txt file according to column in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to sort the following log file according to the InvokeID. It is the last column. The Column although has no header so I can't filter it according to the name. I tried to filter it with the position of the number in the row, sadly didn't find a solution

```
11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace: Sending Query Request message to application gateway host.     11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     ApplicationGatewayID = 5000  11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     InvokeID =             11359032 
11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace: Received Query Confirm message from application gateway host.  11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     ApplicationGatewayID = 5001  11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     InvokeID =             11359018 
11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace: Received Query Confirm message from application gateway host.  11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     ApplicationGatewayID = 5001  11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     InvokeID =             11359017 
11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace: Sending Query Request message to application gateway host.     11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     ApplicationGatewayID = 5000  11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     InvokeID =             11359033 
11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace: Received Query Confirm message from application gateway host.  11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     ApplicationGatewayID = 5000  11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     InvokeID =             11359032
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The log shows no real recognizable columns and seems to prepend values with lots of spaces. You could see this as a `Fixed-Width` table and use my [ConvertFrom-FixedWidth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59543676/9898643) function, but the code below should do what you want:

```
Get-Content -Path 'TheLogFile.log' | Sort-Object @{Expression = { [int]($_.Trim() -split '\s+')[-1] }}
```

Result:

```
11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace: Received Query Confirm message from application gateway host.  11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     ApplicationGatewayID = 5001  11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     InvokeID =             11359017 
11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace: Received Query Confirm message from application gateway host.  11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     ApplicationGatewayID = 5001  11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     InvokeID =             11359018 
11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace: Sending Query Request message to application gateway host.     11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     ApplicationGatewayID = 5000  11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     InvokeID =             11359032 
11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace: Received Query Confirm message from application gateway host.  11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     ApplicationGatewayID = 5000  11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     InvokeID =             11359032
11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace: Sending Query Request message to application gateway host.     11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     ApplicationGatewayID = 5000  11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     InvokeID =             11359033
```

Comment: You might want to explain the -1. First time I see a usefull case to use it.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers The `[-1]` is indexing the last item in the array. As [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7) explain: _Negative numbers count from the end of the array. For example, "-1" refers to the last element of the array. To display the last three elements of the array, in index ascending order, type: `$theArray[-3..-1]`_

Comment: yes I know, it was more meant as an invitation to add an explanation in your answer ;)