# Handling Data & Sorting Results in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, kubectl, text-parsing

I am having trouble manipulating the data returned from a PowerShell query.

My goal is to get all NAMEs that are great than 30 days old (>30d).

After that, I want to load the NAMEs of these results into an array.

The data returned from my query is as follows:

```
PS C:\Users\> $output
NAME                      STATUS   AGE
dread-gorge               Active   284d
dread-lagoon              Active   210d
carncier-basin            Active   164d
chantague-shallows        Active   164d
hilraine-loch             Active   311d
stangrave-waters          Active   271d
```

Running a 'Select-Object' or 'Sort-Object' to filter the output doesn't work.

```
$output | Select-Object -Property NAME
```

```
$output | Sort-Object NAME
```

Comment: Looks like `$output` contains one or more strings, not structured objects. How did you obtain this data in the first place?

Comment: It's output from a kubectl query that I ran in Powershell. So, in it's raw format it's JSON.

Comment: In that case you'll probably want to run your query with `--output=json` and pipe it to `ConvertFrom-Json`

Comment: Is there a way that I can simply grab all the NAMEs from the output above? The JSON is not so easy to manipulate and get value from using ConvertFrom-Json. In some cases "yes" but, not in this instance.

Comment: You could do something like `@($output -split '\r?\n' |Select -Skip 1 |ForEach-Object Trim) -replace '\s.+$'`

Comment: If the output really is space-delimited data, you could skip the first row of the output (the column names) and use a regular expression to grab the first token on each line. But (as Mathias pointed out) it would be better to parse as json data if possible (more precise and direct, less error-prone).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `$output` is a **single multiline string**, you can do this:

```
$result = ($output -split '\r?\n' -replace '\s+', ',' | ConvertFrom-Csv | Where-Object {[int]($_.Age -replace '\D') -gt 30}).NAME
```

to get the Names in an array `$result`.

If `$output` is already an array of strings, do:

```
$result = ($output -replace '\s+', ',' | ConvertFrom-Csv | Where-Object {[int]($_.Age -replace '\D') -gt 30}).NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

Update:

- For a superior solution that transforms the input into CSV format and parses it with [`ConvertFrom-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv), see [Theo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70068689/45375).
- The solution below may be of interest for its text-parsing techniques.

---

As the comments note, it's generally better to make an external program emit *structured* text, such as JSON, because parsing for-display formatted text is inherently brittle.
According to the [`kubectl` docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/#formatting-output), you can use `-o json` to achieve that (as Mathias has also noted).

If the data is simple enough so that plain-text parsing is still an option, you can try the following, which relies on the unary form of the [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) to break each line into fields:

```
# Sample output from kubectl.
# Note: Capturing output from an external programs such as kubectl
#       results in an *array of lines*.
#       The -split '\r?\n` operation splits the multiline here-string into
#       just that.
$kubeCtlOutput = @'
NAME                      STATUS   AGE
dread-gorge               Active   28d
dread-lagoon              Active   31d
carncier-basin            Active   16d
chantague-shallows        Active   164d
'@ -split '\r?\n'

# Process the array's lines.
[array] $namesOfInterest = 
  $kubeCtlOutput | 
    Select-Object -Skip 1 |
      ForEach-Object { 
        $name, $age = (-split $_)[0, -1]
        if ([int] ($age -replace '\D') -gt 30) {
          $name
        }
      }

$namesOfInterest # Print the result.
```

Output, showing that only the names of the two lines whose `AGE` is greater than `30` days were extracted:

```
dread-lagoon
chantague-shallows
```

[This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59599687/45375) has answers that define *generic helper functions* that can parse columnar plain-text data into objects.